# Showing $\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to (0,0)} \frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Can I please receive feedback on my proof for the following? Thanks!

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}} 
\def\x{{\bf x}}
\def\f{{\bf f}}
\def\0{{\bf 0}}$
Let $f\colon \R^2\to \R$ be given by
$$f(\x)=f(x_1,x_2) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} \frac{x^2_1 x_2}{x^4_1+x^2_2} &  \mbox{if $\x\ne\0$,} \\
0             &  \mbox{if $\x=\0$.} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Show $\displaystyle{\lim_{\x\to\0} f(\x)}$
does not exist.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Let us consider that $x_1^2 = x_2$. This can be possible even when $\x\to 0$. Therefore, $$\frac{x^2_1 x_2}{x^4_1+x^2_2} = \frac{1}{\frac{x_1^4}{x_1^2x_2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2x_2}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\frac{x_1^2 }{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1^2}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Next, $$\lim_{\x\to\0} f(\x) = \lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to (0,0)} f(x_1,x_2) \text{ as $x_2$ = 0 then}$$ $$=\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to(0,0)} \frac{x_1^2\cdot 0}{x_1^4+0^2} = \lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to(0,0)} 0 = 0.$$

Observe, we have different limits as $x\to 0$ in different directions. So, $\lim_{\x\to\0} f(\x)$ does not exist.

Comment: This does not quite show $\lim_{\mathbf x\to0}f(\mathbf x)$ does not exist. Rather, you have shown that if the limit *does* exist, it is equal to $\frac12$. All you need to do now is find another path for which the limit is *not* $\frac12$.

Comment: Agreed with @Jason. You did however show that $f$ is not continuous at the origin. This is not the same as the limit not existing

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I will adjust

Comment: @Jason I made an edit to my proof, does it look fine now?

Comment: @AdamMartens I made an edit to my proof, does it look fine now? Thanks

Comment: @rudinsimons12 modulo some stylistic rewording, yes.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry, what do you mean by "modulo some..?" @AdamMartens

Comment: @rudinsimons12 For example, you still have written that "$\lim f$ does not exist" before you can really conclude this fact. Furthermore, you really should not write $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ until you show that this quantity exists. You should instead just point out that approaching $(0,0)$ along different paths yields different results.

Comment: @AdamMartens I see now, thank you. I will fix this right away

Comment: @rudinsimons12 the proof that I'm seeing now is completely fine... you've shown that when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along two different paths then the function yields different limits. Therefore the function doesn't have any unique limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a curve $x_2=mx_1^2, m\ne 0$ so that the limit equals $\frac{m}{1+m^2}$ which depends on $m$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Nitin, do you agree with my proof now? Thanks!

Comment: Yes the proof looks fine if you remove the statement appearing in the middle of your proof "Therefore, in this instance.....occur".

Comment: Thank you so much, fixed it

Comment: You can accept my answer if you find it worth.

Comment: yes, i accept. Thank you